# TEST_F in google mock giving error

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

It's a simple example to use google mocking along with fixtures. I am trying to setup up and learn google mock on Xcode and wrote following code

```
using ::testing::Return;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual int calculateArea() = 0;
    virtual std::string getShapeColor() = 0; // this interface must have been used by some other class under test
};

// Mock class for Shape
class MockShape : public Shape{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(calculateArea, int());
    MOCK_METHOD0(getShapeColor, std::string());
};

// class under test
class Show{   
public:
    Show() : printFlag(false), isColorValid(false) {}

    void printArea(Shape *shape) {
        if (shape->calculateArea() <= 0)
            printFlag = false;
        else
            printFlag = true;
    }

    void printColor(Shape *shape) {
        if (shape->getShapeColor().compare("black"))
            isColorValid = true;
        else
            isColorValid = false;
    }
    bool printFlag;
    bool isColorValid;
};

// Test fixture for class under test
class FixtureShow : public ::testing::Test{
public:
    void SetUp(){}
    void TearDown(){}
    void SetUpTestCase(){}
    void TearDownTestCase(){}

    Show show; // common resources to be used in all the test cases
    MockShape mockedShape;
};

TEST_F(FixtureShow, areaValid) {
    EXPECT_CALL(mockedShape, calculateArea()).WillOnce(Return(5));
    show.printArea(&mockedShape);
    EXPECT_EQ(show.printFlag, true);    
}
```

"TEST_F(FixtureShow, areaValid) " is giving error "Call to non static member function without an object argument". Can anyone help me why am I getting this error?

Comment: Is this the whole error message?

Answer (score 1):

`SetUpTestCase()` and `TearDownTestCase()` are meant to be declared as static member functions. You can also delete them unless you are planning to put some code in.